# Spark: Split stream of elements to stream of lists of elements

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'd like to split an RDD to sequences of elements separated by a delimiter.
Say I have this RDD:

```
val data = Array(1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 0, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 0, 4)
val distData = sc.parallelize(data)
```

I'd like to transform it into the following RDD:

```
(Seq(1, 2), Seq(4, 5), Seq(4, 5, 6, 1, 2), Seq(4))
```

And I'd like to preserve "laziness" of that RDD - that's it, I want to be able to take(n) without evaluating the whole data.

I was able to solve it using accumulator and groupByKey, but unfortunately it won't preserve laziness because groupByKey needs the whole RDD to be evaluated.

```
val seqId = sc.longAccumulator("Sequance id")
distData
  .flatMap { e =>
    if (e == 0) {
      seqId.add(1)
      None
    } else
      Some(seqId.value, e)
  }
  .groupByKey()
  .map { case(id, e) => e.toSeq }
```

Any ideas how to solve this problem in a lazy way?

Comment: take(n) will most likely not evaluate all data, 1 partition minimum. But I am wondering if you are looking for view, stream?

Comment: I think you're right, it's not groupByKey that evaluates the whole RDD. But the last line e.toSeq does, cause it needs to wait till the last element to see if has the same id. Cause it's not aware if id in the RDD is raised, it will never get lower id number.

Comment: I was in more general mode